# How to dynamically allocate memory on the stack in a Cython function?

Tags: cython

I want to allocate **on the stack** a small array whose size is unknown until runtime.

The  following code does not work:

```
cdef void f(unsigned n, double[] x):                                                                                                                                                                
    cdef double[n] buffer
```

Does Cython provide some help with that, or do I have to rely on the [`alloca(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) function?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to use `alloca` from the libc. I don't know ho portable this solution is:

```
cdef extern from "<alloca.h>":                                                                                                                                                                      
    void *alloca(size_t size)                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                    
cdef void f(unsigned n, double[] x):                                                                                                                                                                
    cdef double* buffer = <double*>alloca(n*sizeof(double))  
    ...
```

In the C code, it becomes:

```
  __pyx_v_buffer = ((double *)alloca((__pyx_v_n * (sizeof(double)))));
```

Worth mentioning that GCC inlines the calls to `alloca`.